# Max() is taking quite long is there any alternate way to write this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have written a MySQL query, which is working fine as per needs. What I'm trying to do is searching latest records by hours and mins. 
For example:

```
id, date, value, ip
1 2020-04-22 21:10:14 10 123
2 2020-04-22 21:20:14 20 123
3 2020-04-23 15:26:14 30 123
4 2020-04-23 15:50:14 40 123
5 2020-04-23 18:30:14 50 123
6 2020-04-24 11:05:14 60 123
7 2020-04-24 11:15:14 70 123
```

So my query will return:

```
id, date, value

2 2020-04-22 21:20:14 20 123
4 2020-04-23 15:50:14 40 123
5 2020-04-23 18:30:14 50 123
7 2020-04-24 11:15:14 70 123
```

Here is my query:

```
FROM table_name
WHERE id IN (
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM table_name
WHERE ip = '12345'
GROUP BY HOUR(`date`), DATE(`date`)
)
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

My table has millions of records, I'm trying to figuring out a way through a query. Otherwise, I have another way to do it by Cron Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select t.*
from table_name t
where t.id = (
    select max(t1.id)
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.ip = 12345
        and t1.date >= date_format(t.date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00')
        and t1.date <  date_format(t.date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00') + interval 1 hour
)
```

For performance with this query, you need an index on `(ip, date, id)`.